# When I call any components from react-bootstrap, it will show the below stated error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Accordion, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
        <Card>
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
              Click me!
            </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>Hello! I'm the body</Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    );
  }
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: Have you checked that none of the reasons the error states applies to you? Could you show some code?

Comment: I' ve edited my question with the code pls check my qn

Comment: And what version of React and ReactDOM are you using?

Comment: react=17.0.2
react-dom=17.0.2